# Is there a way to deploy Sitecore JSS components from sitecore cms back to the jss app

Tags: jss

"Jss deploy app" deploys the jss app to sitecore (including components, templates ..etc). Is there a way where I can deploy the components created in sitecore back to JSS app, that way I can view them in disconnected mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to do this with out of the box JSS.

There have been some 3rd party modules developed by the community that add this functionality - https://github.com/macaw-interactive/umbrella-for-sitecore-jss

Comment: Thanks Anastasiya.